# spark reference columns in refactorable way

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, type-safety, apache-spark-dataset

spark sql is awesome. However, columns are inherently referenced by strings. Even for the dataset API only presence of required columns is checked - not absence of additional fields. And my main problem is that even for the dataset API strings are used to reference columns.

Is there a way to **have a more typesafe referencing of columns** in spark sql without introducing an additional data structure for each table (besides the initial case class for the type information) to address the names in order to have better refactoring and IDE support.

## edit

see the snippet below. It will compile even though it should be clear that it is the wrong column reference. Also edit/refactor in IDE does not seem to work properly.

```
case class Foo(bar: Int)
import spark.implicits._
val ds = Seq(Foo(1), Foo(2)).toDS
ds.select('fooWrong)
```

> NOTE:
>
> ```
> import spark.implicits._
> ```
>
> is already imported and `'fooWrong` already resembles a type of column

Answer (score 0):

Frameless seems to be the go to solution which offers the desired properties https://github.com/typelevel/frameless

The only downside is, that currently only joins work with column equality. Allowing for any boolean predicate is still in progress.